# Django Sqlite3 how to insert binary to Blob

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to store binary data (wav data)in the Sqlite3,but just stored the Head "RIFF$" ,how to store the hole data?
this is the server code

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    postDict={}
    req = json.loads(request.body)
    postDict['audioFile']=req['audioFile']
    postDict['textFile']=req['textFile']
    postDict['audioBinary']=sqlite3.Binary(req['audioBinary'])

    if postDict:
        insertToDB(conn,cu,postDict['audioFile'],postDict['textFile'],buffer(postDict['audioBinary']))
```

postDict['audioFile'] and postDict['textFile'] can store rightly but postDict['audioBinary']) only stored "RIFF$",the binary losed,I tested that the POST data is right,just can't store in database.please help me.

Comment: Show the `insertToDB` code.

Comment: `def insertToDB(conn, cu, audioFile, textFile,audioBinary):
    cu.execute("INSERT INTO vrApp_vrrecord(audioFile, textFile,audioBinary) VALUES (?,?,?)", [audioFile, textFile,audioBinary] )
    conn.commit()`

Comment: This is the insertToDB code.I am  sorry for the late reply .

Comment: database tells me the audioBinary is Bad Unicode data.

Comment: thanks for your reply,my problem was solved，I post the bad data.I used the old function `readasbinarystring()`,there are some problems,changed it to `readasarraybuffer()` it run rightly.